# Why handle_info is never called?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to utilize the `handle_info` to track `Presence` of joined users, but I've noticed that `handle_info` is never called, although users are succefully joined and sends/recieve messages..

```
defmodule App.UserChannel do
  use App.Web, :channel
  alias App.Presence

...
...

def handle_info(info, socket) do
  IO.puts info  
  IO.puts "* * * "
  {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user_id, %{
    online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
  })
  push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
  {:noreply, socket}
end

...
...
```

Any idea?

At the server side, within the `App.UserChannel` , how would I know if a certain user is online or offline?

**EDIT**

Do I need to have Elixir 1.3 to have Presence working? I am on Elixir 1.2.6, Phoenix (1.2.0-rc.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Elixir 1.3, but in the example I used on the DailyDrip episode you referenced elsewhere about this issue (https://www.dailydrip.com/topics/elixir/drips/phoenix-presence-chat) my join function has this:

```
def join("room:lobby", msg, socket) do
  send self, {:after_join, msg} # <---
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

If you don't have that, that would explain the behaviour mentioned.

Comment: ah! yes, `send self, {:after_join, msg} ` was missing, thanks

Comment: Have your tried to check if a specific user is online or not at the server side?

Comment: I haven't gotten to that yet, nope.  Sorry!